# Inserting Specific function within a Block. Scripting

Tags: python, perl, shell

Consider you have a file test.cpp with below lines

```
Test(func_class,func1)
{
  Test_Func1();
  Test_Func2();
  Test_Func3();
}

Test(func_class,func3)
{
  Test_Func1();
  Test_Func9();
  Test_Func3();
}

Test(func_class,func2)
{
  Test_Func6();
  Test_Func7();
  Test_Func3();
}
```

Now i want to insert a new line in between the curly braces for e:g in Test(func_class,func1/2/3)
after inserting will be like

```
Test(func_class,func1)
{
  Test_Func1();
  Test_newFunc6();
  Test_Func2();
  Test_Func3();
}

Test(func_class,func3)
{
  Test_Func1();
  Test_newFunc6();
  Test_Func9();
  Test_Func3();
}

Test(func_class,func2)
{
  Test_Func6();
  Test_newFunc6();
  Test_Func7();
  Test_Func3();
}
```

this can be done using scripting . can anyone please suggest shell script or perl python to do this,

Answer (score 0):

Following may help. This is `python` code:

```
cpp = open("test.cpp","r")
lines = cpp.readlines()
printExtraAfterOneLine = False
for line in lines:
  if printExtraAfterOneLine:
    print line
    print '  Test_newFunc6();'
    printExtraAfterOneLine = False
  else:
    if line.strip() == "{":
      printExtraAfterOneLine = True
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `gash.txt` is the input file, and `out.txt` is the output file:

python:

```
extra = '  Test_newFunc6();\n'

fh  = open('gash.txt')
out = open('out.txt','w')

for line in fh:
    out.write(line)
    if line.startswith('{'):
        # Read the next line
        buff = fh.readline()
        out.write(buff)
        out.write(extra)

fh.close()
out.close()
```

perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $extra = "  Test_newFunc6();\n";

open(my $fh, '<', 'gash.txt') || die "gash.txt: $!";
open(my $out, '>', 'out.txt') || die "out.txt: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print $out $_;
    if (substr($_, 0, 1) eq '{') {
        # Read the next line
        my $buff = <$fh>;
        print $out $buff;
        print $out $extra;
    }
}

close($fh);
close($out);
```

bash:

```
extra="  Test_newFunc6();\n";
wFlag=false

exec 3> out.txt

IFS=
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" >&3

    $wFlag && echo "$extra" >&3

    if [[ ${line:0:1} == '{' ]]
    then
        wFlag=true
    else
        wFlag=false
    fi
done < gash.txt

exec 3<&-
```